# Problem with backtrader live Gold (XAUUSD) data from IB (Interactive Brokers)

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, back-testing, backtrader

Backtrader works fine with live data of IB (Interactive Brokers) through TWS, but when I want to trade on gold commodity (XAUUSD), it cannot receive the data.
the python code is:

```
data = store.getdata(dataname='XAUUSD', sectype='CMDTY', exchange='SMART', timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Minutes)
```

I follow the instruction in:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spot Gold (symbol XAUUSD) is a commodities  product offered by IB to trade gold in the OTC London metals market.

Most probably you want to trade CFD with the same symbol. In this case use `sectype='CFD'` and `exchange='IBCFD'`

Comment: Thanks @yuri-ginsburg, but I considered IB api details for gold commodity in: interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/basic_contracts.html

Comment: I edited the question by adding the IB broker picture for details of the XAUUSD commodity.

Comment: I saw this picture. Also I can see quotes for both `XAUUSD` contracts `CMDTY` and  `CFD` in my TWS, but API request returns an empty list.